# Transfer data from PHP(client) to a Python script(server)

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, http

I will be writing a python script which takes user_id as parameter from PHP and performs some operations on it. When it is done performing operations, it waits for another user_id. What I want to do is:

1. Send $user_id from PHP to Python
2. Run script.py in the background as a daemon with the filename that came from PHP.
3. Handle multiple user_id inputs while it is processing a single user_id (maybe user a queue)

I cannot send parameter to python script that already runs at the background.

When user clicks a button on the PHP website some data is sent to the python script and is processed. Python script maintains a queue to manage requests from multiple users and process them one by one. The scripts runs in background so the there is no need to return value to back to PHP script.

How can I implement this type of functionality? Any ideas?

I cannot pass data through arguments using

```
 exec('python script.py args');
```

as it will start a new process for every user click and the OS won't be able to handle processes if 1000 users click at the same time.

I somehow want to execute the script form PHP and then be able to transfer data to it in real time.

Comment: You can't magically turn python into a server that supports sustained socket connections.  The limitations of the way the python script has been coded will be the limitation of what a client (in this case a server side PHP script I suppose?)  can do.  You say that `I cannot pass data through arguments using...`.  Well if that is true, how do you plan to get data to the python script?

Comment: @gview Is passing data through arguments the only way to send data from PHP to Python?

Comment: No it's not, but the important question is what can the python script accept?

Comment: When  user clicks the button on PHP website, his user_id is sent to the python script, which writes a user_id.txt file after performing some more operations on it in the web server directory. The python script needs user_id from the PHP script.

Comment: I get that, but if the python script only accepts input of this user_id as a command line parameter, there is nothing PHP can do but exec the program and pass the parameter.  As you noted, this will fork the program.

Comment: That's what I want the answer for. How can I implement  PHP(client) and Python(server) in such a way that I don't need to pass data through arguments.?
One way might be to daemonize the Python script (as I read while researching) but I am not sure how to do this and pass data to this python script from PHP(client) side.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different answers to your question, but they all require that you add to your Python program, and transform it from a command line program into something different.

My suggestion to you would be that you utilize the Python v3 [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/http.server.html?highlight=http%20server#module-http.server) or in v2, the SimpleHTTPServer.

This will then allow your PHP program to send the data to the Python script via localhost:port# using the curl extension or via [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Comment: I never said that the Python program is a command line program, I haven't coded it yet. I need the answer to how can I write a Python program so that it is able to communicate with PHP(client side). 
and how can I send data from PHP to my python program?
Thanks for your answer though, I'll try running python program as an http server and send data to it from php(client) using POST requests. Hope it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes it will certainly work.  Your question says:  `I have a python script`.  Writing it that way, is stating that you already have the question.  It would be better if you said:  "I will be writing a Python script that...."  Best of luck to you.